# Automatically refresh the web page after updating the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

I have developed a web page using php and mysql lanuages. But,I want to refresh the web page which is run on local host  automatically after updating the connected database.How can I do it?

Comment: Socket, nodejs, setinterval ajax request ...

Comment: What about trying with just ajax and refresh only the updated sections of the page?

Comment: I couldn't understand that one@Eka .Anyone can give an example code to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **mysql_affected_rows()** function it returns the number of affected rows on success in case of insert,update and delete and -1 on failure.
check if condition is success use **setTimeout**(function(){location.reload();}, 500); to refresh the page automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Do an AJAX request that goes to PHP function that makes the update. If should check the status of the update (success, failure etc) and deliver that back to the JavaScript. If fail, print a message to HTML. If success, do:

```
window.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

after the connection is done write in javascript this line

```
window.reload();
```

Comment: can you explain it using example code